# Flyway migration do not start in play framework project

Tags: playframework, flyway

I'm new to flyway, and I couldn't find a linear guide on how to set it up on an existing framework play project. Therefore following the guides I imported the libraries by setting them in the **configuration.conf**
 and **build.sbt**. Then I put the various migration files into a default directory in conf / db / migration / default.
After running the project the execution stopped with to :

> INFO  play.api.Play  Application started (Dev) WARN  flyway  Directory
>   for migration files not found. db/migration/default

How can I solve?

Answer (score 0):

simply put your migration files into `conf.db.migration`.